# Почему kivy ScrollView постоянно возвращает вверх, не давая прокрутить вниз

Tags: python, kivy, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Делаю простенький блокнот для смартфонов, сделал по сути всё - можно что-нибудь добавить, написать, и удалить, осталось сделать только отображение кнопки перехода на каждый отдельный блокнот в столбик, чтобы можно было прокручивать вниз и вверх в поисках нужной заметки.

Для этого я добавил все кнопки в GridLayout, а его в ScrollView, и выглядит всё нормально, да вот только если я пытаюсь прокрутить вниз, то он банально возвращает к началу, как будто я пытаюсь листать куда-то за края, но это не так, там снизу есть ещё кнопки, к которым у меня нет доступа, так как он просто не даёт до них долистать.

Вот код в kv файле:

```
ChoiceWindow:
    Crutch1:
    ChoiceMenu1:
    TextWindow1:
    TextWindow2:
    TextWindow3:
    TextWindow4:
    TextWindow5:
    TextWindow6:
    TextWindow7:
    TextWindow8:
    TextWindow9:
    TextWindow10:
    TextWindow11:
    TextWindow12:
    TextWindow13:
 
<Crutch1>:
    name: "crutch"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            text: "Блокнот с подвохом"
            font_size: 40
            background_color: (0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
<ChoiceMenu1>:
    name: "choice_menu"
    on_pre_enter:
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_1, 1)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_2, 2)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_3, 3)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_4, 4)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_5, 5)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_6, 6)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_7, 7)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_8, 8)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_9, 9)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_10, 10)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_11, 11)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_12, 12)
        root.title_on_menu(notebook_13, 13)
        #oelpfb66koojhhfikckckkck
```

вот в нём ScrollView

```
    ScrollView:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.9}
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            cols: 1
            padding: 5
            spacing: 5
            Button: #1
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_1
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '1 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #2
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_2
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '2 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #3
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_3
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '3 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #4
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_4
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '4 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #5
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_5
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '5 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #6
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_6
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '6 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #7
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_7
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '7 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #8
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_8
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '8 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #9
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_9
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '9 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #10
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_10
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '10 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #11
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_11
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '11 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #12
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_12
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '12 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            Button: #13
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: 0, 60
                font_size: 20
                background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
                id: notebook_13
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = '13 notebook'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'

           #lgplveiok3203kov0303vojIJVO
```

остальное:

```
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            text: "+ Добавить новый блокнот"
            font_size: 25
            background_color: (0.7,0.8,0.1,1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3,0.5,0.9,1)
            on_release:
                root.create_notebook()
<TextWindow1>:
    name: '1 notebook'
    on_pre_enter:
        root.load_text(text_input, 1)
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Сохранить'
            font_size: 20
            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            on_press:
                root.save_text(text_input, 1)
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Удалить'
            font_size: 20
            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            on_press:
                root.delete_text(1)
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.9}
        size_hint: 1, 0.9
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id: text_input
<TextWindow2>:
    name: '2 notebook'
    on_pre_enter:
        root.load_text(text_input, 2)
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Сохранить'
            font_size: 20
            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            on_press:
                root.save_text(text_input, 2)
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Удалить'
            font_size: 20
            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            on_press:
                root.delete_text(2)
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.9}
        size_hint: 1, 0.9
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id: text_input

 ***

<TextWindow12>:
    name: '12 notebook'
    on_pre_enter:
        root.load_text(text_input, 12)
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Сохранить'
            font_size: 20
            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            on_press:
                root.save_text(text_input, 12)
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Удалить'
            font_size: 20
            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            on_press:
                root.delete_text(12)
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.9}
        size_hint: 1, 0.9
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id: text_input
<TextWindow13>:
    name: '13 notebook'
    on_pre_enter:
        root.load_text(text_input, 13)
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Сохранить'
            font_size: 20
            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            on_press:
                root.save_text(text_input, 13)
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'Удалить'
            font_size: 20
            background_color: (0.5, 0.8, 0.91, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1)
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'choice_menu'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            on_press:
                root.delete_text(13)
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.9}
        size_hint: 1, 0.9
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id: text_input

#krmbfgrlp45-lh5-hkogkr94jg94gpoekfp309
```

Вот main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
import sys
import os
import re


Window.size = (500, 750)
Window.clearcolor = (12/255, 12/255, 12/255, 1)
Window.title = "Блокнот с подвохом"

***

class ChoiceMenu1(Screen):
    def title_on_menu(self, input, nu):
        standard_title_on_menu(self, input, nu)

class Crutch1(Screen):
    pass

***

class TextWindow1(Screen):
   def load_text(self, input, nu):
       standard_load_text(self, input, nu)
   def save_text(self, input, nu):
       standard_save_text(self, input, nu)
   def delete_text(self, nu):
       standard_delete_text(self, nu)

class TextWindow2(Screen):
   def load_text(self, input, nu):
       standard_load_text(self, input, nu)
   def save_text(self, input, nu):
       standard_save_text(self, input, nu)
   def delete_text(self, nu):
       standard_delete_text(self, nu)

 ***

class TextWindow12(Screen):
   def load_text(self, input, nu):
       standard_load_text(self, input, nu)
   def save_text(self, input, nu):
       standard_save_text(self, input, nu)
   def delete_text(self, nu):
       standard_delete_text(self, nu)

class TextWindow13(Screen):
   def load_text(self, input, nu):
       standard_load_text(self, input, nu)
   def save_text(self, input, nu):
       standard_save_text(self, input, nu)
   def delete_text(self, nu):
       standard_delete_text(self, nu)

# ormhldmbrlgpfbk5bdf4bpvbps

***

class ChoiceWindow(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("new_windows.kv")

class GayApp1(App):
    def build(self):

        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GayApp1().run()
```

не могу понять, в чём причина такого повидения при прокрутке, думаю, что забыл указать какой-нибудь параметр, но какой не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что я забыл выставить высоту в GridLayout, из-за чего он и считал что я листаю за край.

так-что я дописал в GridLayout:

```
height:self.minimum_height
```

и он начал нормально себя вести.